# Attribute Error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, attributes, pygame

This code is to create a walking animation. I dont know what is causing an attribute error.

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def init(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.init(self)
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets','Arts','xeonsheet','xeonsheet_' + str(i) + '.png'))
            self.images.append(img)
            self.images = self.images[0]
            self.images = self.images.get_rect

player = player()
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Dreamwind-Chronicles/main.py", line 121, in <module>
    player = player()
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Dreamwind-Chronicles/main.py", line 117, in init
    self.images.append(img)
Attribute Error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do in the `__init__` method (BTW, you have to add two underscores before and after `init`) and read the ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fully clear what your final intention is, but tracing through the code, I can see you are overwriting `self.images` with the `get_rect` function.

```
self.images.append(img)
self.images = self.images[0]
self.images = self.images.get_rect
```

Once this code repeats, `self.images` is now the `get_rect` function.
I'm guessing that you'll just want to remove those last two lines and then access the properties of the image at the time you render them?

Answer (score -1):

The first time while inserting an object to list it should be insert

```
array = []
array.insert(index,{Object})
array.append({Object})
```

I think by this the error will be solved

Comment: `array.append()` asserts at the end (even if the list is empty). `array.insert` expects an index to insert at as well `list.insert(index, obj)`