# What causes the attribute problems?

Tags: attributes, pygame

What is problem with the attribute?

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets','Arts','xeonsheet','xeonsheet_' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            self.images.append(img)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect = self.images.get_rect()

    def control(self, x, y):  #Control player movement

        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):    #Update sprite position

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0


        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0


player = player()
player.rect.x = 0
player.rect.y = 0
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
ani = 4
steps = 10
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/Dreamwind-Chronicles/main.py", line 148, in <module>
    player = player()
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/Dreamwind-Chronicles/main.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.rect = self.images.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

Comment: `self.images` is a *list*, which doesn't have that attribute. This is what the error message tells you, it's unclear what you thought would happen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do u recommend me to solve this problem?

Comment: That's my point; given that you haven't specified the expected behaviour, how can someone tell you what you *should* have done? All we can tell you right now is what the error message already does, so the question is pointless. What causes that error? The fact that a list indeed does not have that attribute; why did you think it would? Give a proper [mcve] and maybe someone can help.

Comment: It looks like you want the rect of `self.image` not `self.images`: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`. Also, it doesn't make sense to do that in the for loop, because you get a new image and rect each iteration.

Comment: It looks like this is a double-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730125/attribute-error-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-append/48730266

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attribute Error: 'builtin\_function\_or\_method' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730125/attribute-error-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to create a `Rect` object from the `self.images` list. The problem here is that `self.images` is a **list** and not a `pygame.image`, therefore it doesn't have a `get_rect()` method. What you should be doing is getting the `Rect` from one of the images **in** that list.

Another problem is that you're running this code in the for loop, so each image's rect is getting overwritten by the proceeding image.

Your code should look something like this:

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.movex = 0
    self.movey = 0
    self.frame = 0
    self.images = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets','Arts','xeonsheet','xeonsheet_' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect() #The part that was changed

def control(self, x, y):  #Control player movement

    self.movex += x
    self.movey += y

def update(self):    #Update sprite position

    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

    # moving left
    if self.movex < 0:
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > 3 * ani:
            self.frame = 0


    # moving right
    if self.movex > 0:
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > 3 * ani:
            self.frame = 0
```

But, this is assuming that every image in your `self.images` list is the same size. If they are sized differently, the `Rect` of the player will only be scaled to the first image. To change this, you could update the `self.rect` in the update method. However, I'm not going to expand on this as it's not really part of the question.